# Eeepc Ubuntu 14.04 Problems: Video, audio, screen flicking and suspend failure

Tags: sound, video, suspend, screen, eeepc

I install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Eeepc 1101HA with processor Intel Atom CPUZ520 and I have some problems:

1. Screen is flicking, shacking.....
2. Video doesn-t work, is very slow and impossible to see anything.
3. Audio doesn/t work either, it jumps....
4. Once the pc go to sleep I can~t restart, without shutting down and turning on again.

I have no experience with Ubuntu at all, but I so happy to get out of Windows that I will try hard to stay with Ubuntu. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a too weak CPU and graphics for videos.

You can try a tweak that helps some intel graphics chips, UXA acceleration.
This should increase the performance, but there seem to be issues with the login screen with this fix.

Edit (or create) `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` as follows:

```
Section "Device"
            Identifier "Intel Graphics"
            Driver "intel"
            Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
EndSection
```

Then reboot the system.

Another way would be to try a lighter linux spin like lubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

use these values to try to solve

1. Screen is flickering, shaking: edit or create `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-modesetting.conf` and add

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier  "gma500_gfx"
       Driver      "modesetting"
       Option     "SWCursor"       "ON"
   EndSection
   ```
2. Video doesn-t work, is very slow and impossible to see anything: edit or create `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-modesetting.conf` and add

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier  "gma500_gfx"
       Driver      "modesetting"
       Option     "SWCursor"       "ON"
   EndSection
   ```
3. Audio doesn/t work either, it jumps: edit or create `/etc/pulse/default.pa` change

   ```
   load-module module-udev-detect
   ```

   to

   ```
   load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
   ```
4. Once the pc go to sleep I can't restart, without shutting down and turning on again.

   edit or create `/etc/pm/config.d/gma500` add

   ```
   ADD_PARAMETERS='--quirk-vbemode-restore'
   ```

I hope you solve with this.
Keep on gma500 with linux has poor performances.

Good luck!